# Release signed apk of react-native (0.59.9) not crashing on version 5.1.1 android devices,but crashing on version 6 and 7 devices

Tags: macos, android-studio

I created a project using react-native version 0.59.9 with minimum sdk version 16,target sdk version 28.When I generate debug apk,it works fine on device,but I generated release apk using android studio with jks file.It is  installed but crashing on app startup on vivo y21ll(version 5.1.1),but installed and working fine on Redmi note 5(version 6).
My **android/app/build.gradle** file is:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <--- this should be 
the last line

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/** * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant 
(e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct 
  arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in 
 debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all 
 the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make 
 sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if 
 configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user- 
 guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by 
 default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if 
 configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the 
 ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the 
 ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files 
 or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine 
 whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for 
 performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you 
 have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional 
 arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
  */

 project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
  ]

  apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

 /**
  * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
  *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
  *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
  * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
  * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
  * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
  */
  def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

  /**
  * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
  */
  def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

  android {
     compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tapontech.wrapoconnect"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version 
 code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user- 
  guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, 
   "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal- 
   release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + 
 defaultConfig.versionCode
           }
        }
     }
  }

 dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-google-signin')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-view-pdf')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"

   implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.0'
     implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-cookies')
   implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
   implementation "com.android.support:appcompat- 
  v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From 
     node_modules
   }

 // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
 // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
 task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
  }
```

my **android/build.gradle** is:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
  common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
   ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0')
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
        belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
   }

   allprojects {
     repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
       jcenter()
        maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is 
         installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
       }
     }
   }
```

my **android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties** is:

```
   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle- 
   5.4.1-all.zip
   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

my **package.json** file is:

```
    {
    "name": "Wrapo",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
   "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
   },
 "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-cookies": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.4",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.13",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.9.11",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-linkedin": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-options-menu": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.8.6",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "striptags": "^3.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
   },
"devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "7.5.0",
   "@babel/runtime": "7.5.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
   "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.55.0",
   "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
     "preset": "react-native"
    }
  }
```

Please get me some clues where I went wrong or what else extra steps I can do..to make it work in all devices.

Comment: Well,I will answer to my own question.Actually debug apk also was  not working on vivo y21l(5.1.1).So it made easy to find the issue.There was a problem with react-native-device-info package version.I changed the version from  2.2.1 form 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've **enabled "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds"** in your **app-level build.gradle** file. By enabling this, you're instructing the gradle to run proguard to shrink the Java byte-code in release builds which ensures small size of release APKs.

To solve this issue we have two approaches:

first is to disable enableProguardInReleaseBuilds in your **app-level build.gradle** file

```
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
```

You are using **react-native-fbsdk** which is causing the crash in the release build. During the Facebook authentication process, the Fbsdk accesses native webview for Facebook authentication. When enableProguardInReleaseBuilds is enabled it shrinks the Fbsdk java byte-code also due to which we it cannot access the native webview and it leads to crash. So if you do not want to disable the enableProguardInReleaseBuilds and your priority is lesser APK size then no need to change anything in app-level build.gradle file, just keep it as it is:

```
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

and add the following piece of code in your **proguard-rules.pro** file present in your android app folder

```
    -keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip
    -keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters
    -keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip

    # Do not strip any method/class that is annotated with @DoNotStrip
    -keep @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip class *
    -keep @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip class *
    -keepclassmembers class * {
        @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip *;
        @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip *;
    }

    -keepclassmembers @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters class * {
      void set*(***);
      *** get*();
    }

    -keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule { *; }
    -keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule { *; }
    -keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * { native <methods>; }
    -keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIProp <fields>; }
    -keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp <methods>; }
    -keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup <methods>; }

    -dontwarn com.facebook.react.**

    # okhttp

    -keepattributes Signature
    -keepattributes *Annotation*
    -keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
    -keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
    -dontwarn okhttp3.**

    # okio

    -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
    -dontwarn java.nio.file.*
    -dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
    -dontwarn okio.**

    -keepclassmembers class * {
        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
    }

    -keepattributes JavascriptInterface
    -keepattributes *Annotation*

    -dontwarn com.facebook.**
    -keep class com.facebook.** {*;}

    -optimizations !method/inlining/*

    -ignorewarnings
    -keep class * {
        public private *;
    }
```

Though you can build separate APKs for different CPU architectures which can further reduce your size to 1/3rd of the current version by enabling **enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture** in your **app-level build.gradle** file

```
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
```

I faced similar issues while integrating Facebook authentication, Razorpay payment gateway and all those SDKs which access native webviews through react-native bridge and solved them in a similar fashion as stated above.

Comment: This answer includes Facebook SDK (Fbsdk) issues in integrating Facebook authentication with android and react-native apps i.e. it works fine in debug apk but app crashes on startup in release apk